# Xcodebuild not generating dynamic framework with x86_64 architecture

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcodebuild

I am using xcodebuild command to generate dynamic framework. To make it compatible with iPhone 5s simulator I need to build it with x86_64 architecture. but it is not building the framework.

I am using below command for that.

```
xcodebuild -project $PROJECT_PATH -configuration 'Release' -sdk 'iphonesimulator7.0' clean build ARCHS='x86_64' VALID_ARCHS='x86_64' IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='7.0' TARGET_BUILD_DIR="$BUILD_DIR/build-x86_64" BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR="BUILD_DIR/build-x86_64"
```

Please help...

Comment: Couldn't generate it in XCode?

Comment: Is the framework project listed as a dependency in the Build Phases?  Xcode will resolve dependencies implicitly but the command line will not.

Comment: It is generated while I am using xcode but not generating through xcodebuild command.

Comment: I have put four xcodebuild commands in run script of aggregate target. Three architecture are generating the framework but x86_64 is not generating anything.

Comment: Is the command you show for the framework or for a project that uses the framework?  Oh by the way, x86_64 is not correct for iPhone 5S.  The correct architecture is arm64.

Comment: I want to support it for iPhone5s simulator. And I am generating Dynamic framework. I just want that my framework support all iPhone simulators and all devices.

Comment: What error message are you actually getting? And once you build all the binaries with all the necessary architecture slices, are you using lipo to combine them all into a universal library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers..

I just found that iphonesimulator7.0 SDK was not installed on my machine so it was failed while building.

I changed it to iphonesimulator and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you are missing the `-target "MyTarget"` parameter. By default, if you don't pass this parameter, `xcodebuild` will build the first target listed in the project. Is your desired target the first target in the project?

Another option you could try is using a tried and tested method for building universal frameworks for iOS. I have used the method described here with many frameworks with perfect results: https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework. I am not the developer of this method.

Without posting any error messages or even how you know that it is failing, it is hard to give you more details. Is it failing to build (so you get an error message)? Is it failing because you don't see the `x86_64` architecture in the final framework?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in the list of arguments
[xcodebuild manual link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html)

```
-destination "platform=iOS Simulator,OS=8.0,name=iPhone 6"
```

This is what is displayed for a project(I'm making this assumption based on your context above)

```
 xcodebuild [-project projectname] -scheme schemename [-destination destinationspecifier]
            [-destination-timeout value] [-configuration configurationname]
            [-sdk [sdkfullpath | sdkname]] [buildaction ...] [setting=value ...]
            [-userdefault=value ...]
```

In one of their examples you can also list multiple destinations.

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme MyScheme -destination 'platform=iOS
          Simulator,name=iPhone' -destination 'platform=iOS,name=My iPad' test
```

I am personally in a project that uses a workspace, so I have to list a scheme.

Side note, I noticed you are setting the TARGET_BUILD_DIR and BUILD_PRODUCTS. I set OBJROOT and SYMROOT and the directories come out the same as they would had I used the Xcode GUI.

Last here is a real example of using the destination flag

```
BUILDDIR="<path/to/build/directory>"
xcodebuild -workspace "<path/to/workspace/>my.xcworkspace" -scheme "NameOfMySchemeToBuild" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,OS=8.0,name=iPhone 6" -configuration "Release" OBJROOT=$BUILDDIR SYMROOT=$BUILDDIR
```

Hope this helps!